# Giving a DNS name to Azure Load Balancer

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I have created a Load Balancer with public IP. Based on the documentation, I can access the LB with the following FQDN : 'LB name'.'region'.cloudapp.azure.com

It is not working.

When you create a VM, you have option when you click on the public IP link of the machine to add DNS name, but when doing the same from the LB setting, it does not give this option. Just to choose if this IP is dynamic or static.

Comment: hey mate, consider accepting this answer

Answer (score 13):

Just go directly to the Public IP (that's tied to the LB) settings and assign DNS name to it. It wont work if you navigate to it from within LB settings.

[image]

Comment: I think a key point here is you need to actually look for the public ip resource. if you navigate from the LB you don't actually get an option to change that.

Comment: thats what my answer says? @CtrlDot edited it to be more clear, although I dont see how "go directly to Public Ip settings" can be interpreted in a wrong way :)

Comment: I can't find a way to access it in 2023. Has it been removed as a resource and integrated as part of vnet resource?

Answer (score 1):

one option is to create a public IP address first
Home:New:Public IP address then you will get a dns `yourname`.´yourlocation’.cloudapp.azure.com
Same you can assign when creating the load balancer.